# Setting values to multiple child nodes Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set values to multiple child nodes in Firebase but when I try to do this android studio highlights the second child as an error. Is there any way of doing this without using a hashmap?

```
mDatabaseLike.child("ProjectName").setValue(uploadCurrent.getName()).child("Votes/").setValue(mCountLikes);
```

I want my firebase to be stored as:

```
CountLikes:{
      ProjectName: "abcd"
      Votes: "78"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your only other alternative to using a Map is to use a Java object whose members have the values that you want to add.  It will go something like this:

```
class YourObject {
    public String ProjectName;
    public int Votes;
}

YourObject o = new YourObject();
o.ProjectName = "abcd";
o.Votes = 78;
mDatabaseLike.setValue(o);
```

Comment: Note that a POJO/Java object is only accepted as an argument to `setValue()`, so any values at `mDatabaseLike` that do not exist in `YourObject` will be deleted with this approach. This may or may not be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Doug's answer is perfectly fine when you want to populate a node with data from a POJO class, in this case with your ProjectName and Votes, but as Frank's comment says, if you had old data at that node before placing the new one, it will be overwrited/deleted from that node.

For example, if you had this at your node

```
CountLikes:{
      ProjectName: "MyAwesomeProject"
      Votes: "100"
      comments: 20  --> New data that you could add or have
      flags: 0 --> New data that you could add or have
      favorites: 30 --> New data that you could add or have
}
```

before doing this

```
YourObject o = new YourObject();
o.ProjectName = "abcd";
o.Votes = 78;
mDatabaseLike.setValue(o);
```

All that old data you had at that node will be replaced with this

```
CountLikes:{
      ProjectName: "abcd"
      Votes: "78"
}
```

If you only need to update/change your data at that particular node, I would suggest doing it with the `HashMap`, because it will just update the values inside that node and not recreate them again and replace/delete them if you already had data there.

Continuing Doug's answer

```
    class YourObject {
        public String ProjectName;
        public int Votes;
    }

 String projectName = "abcd";
 int votes = 78;
 Map<String,Object> mapData = new HashMap<>();
 mapData.put("ProjectName",projectName);
 mapData.put("Votes",votes);
 mDatabaseLike.updateChildren(mapData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task){
                //Data pushed succefully, update UI or do something else.
            }
        });
```

Doing this will prevent recreating the whole object and just replacing that data inside your node, I know you requested without a HashMap, but I just post why it's a good choice doing it this way.